# How to refresh changes made in my React.js app without having to kill the server and restart it every time?

Tags: reactjs, refresh

I am reaching out to you because after watching countless articles and tutorials, I still can't solve my problem. I recently started using React.js and every time I want to refresh the changes I made to my app content, I have to "kill" the local server 3000 and restart it (which is very time-consuming even for minor changes). When I watch tutorials, the content refreshes instantly for those people, so if you have any ideas, they are more than welcome!

I have reinstalled CRA and Node.js multiple times but nothing seems to change. Also, I should mention that I am quite new to React.js, so it's possible that I might have missed something! Thank you for taking the time to respond :)

Comment: Which command do you use to start the server?

Comment: i use "npm start"

Comment: are you using WSL2 Ubuntu ?

Comment: Yes, i am using ubuntu wsl2 and chrome browser